# react context update not re-rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

According to the react [documentation for context provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider):

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render
> whenever the Provider’s value prop changes.

I am trying to update a context value from a sibling component (B) and read that update from sibling component (A).

Heres a simple example of what im trying:

```
import { useState, useContext, createContext } from "react";

export const AnalyseCtx = createContext({ greeting: "hello" });

export default function App() {
  const [context, setContext] = useState({ greeting: "hello" });

  console.log("rendering App");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AnalyseCtx.Provider value={{ context, setContext }}>
        <ComponentA />
        <ComponentB />
      </AnalyseCtx.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

function ComponentA() {
  const analyseContext = useContext(AnalyseCtx);
  console.log("rendering ComponentA");
  return (
    <h4>I display the context value: {analyseContext.context.greeting}</h4>
  );
}

function ComponentB() {
  console.log("rendering ComponentB");
  const analyseContext = useContext(AnalyseCtx);
  analyseContext.setContext((prevState) => {
    prevState.greeting = "updated greeting";
    console.log("updated greeting: ", prevState);
    return prevState;
  });

  return <h4>I update context value</h4>;
}
```

I have also created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-surf-oh0ivo?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate the issue as well.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've been stuck on this problem for a whole day.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component B is mutating the state object instead of returning a new state object reference. Shallow copy the previous state object into a new object reference and overwrite the properties you want to update.

Another issue is that component B is updating the context value as an unintentional side-effect. The update should be done from the `useEffect` hook so it's unconditionally enqueueing state updates and creating conditions for infinite render looping.

```
function ComponentB() {
  const { setContext } = useContext(AnalyseCtx);

  useEffect(() => {
    setContext(state => ({
      ...state,
      greeting: "updated greeting",
    }));
  }, []);

  return <h4>I update context value</h4>;
}
```

[image: Edit react-context-update-not-re-rendering-component]

Comment: woah thank you! I feel dumb. I will accept the answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: I have added a [codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-ully-uzcwyl?file=/src/App.js) to update context on a button click to demonstrate conditional updates. UseEffect with an empty dependency array will only update your context on mount of Component B. @Drew correctly mentioned that you should make shallow copies of your state. Read more about this under the subheading [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) in the React Docs.